# cant access location query string in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

my login.js

```
function handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        if(!event.currentTarget.checkValidity()) return setValidated(true);

        setLoading(true);

        fetch('http://localhost:5000/usersystem/user/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: 'include',
            mode: 'cors',
            body:new URLSearchParams({email: email, password: password})
        }).then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            if(!response.success){
                setLoading(false);
                setErrorMessages(response.msg);
            } else {
                const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
                const redirectTo = params.has('redirect') ? params.get('redirect') : '/';
                setIsLoggedIn(true);
                history.push(redirectTo); 
            }
        })
        
    }
```

my protectedroute.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAppContext } from "../libs/ContextLib";

export default function ProtectedRoute({ children, ...rest }) {
  const { pathname, search } = useLocation();
  const { isLoggedIn } = useAppContext();
    
  return (
    <Route {...rest}>
      {isLoggedIn ? (
        children
      ) : (
        <Redirect to={
          `/login?redirect=${pathname}${search}`
        } />
      )}
    </Route>
  );
}
```

My problem is when user is not logged in and get a link like myapp.com/quotes/:id, then router forces login page with a query string (in this example myapp.com/login?redirect=/quotes/xxxxx) and in login submit in the last else statement params is empty: `const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);`

how to access this redirect query string properly in react in this case? I am sitting on this for 2 hours now, with no luck. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: https://reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters

Comment: thank you it worked with this: ```new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);``` instead of  ```new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);```. if you want you can answer it and ill mark it.